# Add eventlistener to multiple elements on Light DOM in Polymer 1

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0, addeventlistener, web-component

I am working on a project which still uses Polymer 1.

I have a "parent" html document where i use a custom polymer webcomponent.
I have most of the html in the parent element inside of the component's tags, something like this:

```
<my-component>
  some html elements on the light dom of my component
  for example a list of links
</my-component>
```

then, inside of my-component.html i have some logic for the element.
I would now like to add some event listeners to the elements on the light DOM. I have done this by using the normal JS addEventListener on the attached function, but i am sure polymer has a better way to do this.

So, my question is **how can i add custom event listeners to multiple elements on the light DOM?** For instance, how can i add an event listener to that list of links?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just use the platform.

```
this.addEventListener(type, callback)
```

Events bubble up by default, so your element will catch all children's events.

Comment: this sounds like something in the good direction. But how can i add different callbacks to different elements. for instance  callbackA to the link buttons and callbackB to some other buttons on the page?

Comment: You can use the mutation observer to get changes to the Dom tree and react accordingly. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: but isn't that even more complicated than just using the addEventListeners on the elements themselves? What i was wondering was is **Polymer 1** has a good way to do this, maybe using the listeners array?